# LWJGL VBO rendering issues

Tags: opengl, crash, rendering, lwjgl, vbo

I have been having an issue with a game that i have been making. i was using the immediate rendering mode for displaying things on the screen but as i started to add more and more objects to the screen my fps started to drop quickly. I want to use VBO's to render everything in game so i attempted to draw a quad with different colors for each vertex like many tutorials and examples explain how to do. the problem is that when i try to render the vbo using gldrawarrays() with the color buffer enabled (using glcolorpointer and glvertexpointer) it gives me the error:

```
A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00000000504b6ee0, pid=22964, tid=23500

JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_45-b18) (build 1.7.0_45-b18)
Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.45-b08 mixed mode windows-amd64       compressed oops)
Problematic frame:
C  [atio6axx.dll+0x226ee0]

Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of         Windows

An error report file with more information is saved as:
C:\Users\Tyler\Dropbox\Programming\Harry Hank\hs_err_pid22964.log
```

when i don't use glcolorpointer and just set a single color using glcolor3f it renders a quad with the color i assigned it. the failure point is at gldrawarrays and has something to do with the color buffer that is causing it to crash. It doesn't look like there is any reason for it to fail to me. but is there something i'm missing or something that i have done wrong? here is the code i used for the vbo's:

Initialization:

```
numOfVertices = 4;
vertexSize = 2;
colorSize = 4;

vertexData = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(numOfVertices * vertexSize);
vertexData.put(new float[]{10f, 10f,
        100f, 10f,
        100f, 100f,
        10f, 100f});
vertexData.flip();

colorData = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(numOfVertices * colorSize);
colorData.put(new float[]{1f, 0f, 0f,
        0f, 1f, 0f,
        0f, 0f, 1f,
        0f, 1f, 1f});
colorData.flip();

vertHandle = GL15.glGenBuffers();
GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertHandle);
GL15.glBufferData(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexData, GL15.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

colorHandle = GL15.glGenBuffers();
GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, colorHandle);
GL15.glBufferData(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, colorData, GL15.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
```

Rendering:

```
GL11.glEnableClientState(GL11.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
GL11.glEnableClientState(GL11.GL_COLOR_ARRAY);

GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertHandle);
GL11.glVertexPointer(vertexSize, GL11.GL_FLOAT, 0, 0l);

GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, colorHandle);
GL11.glVertexPointer(colorSize, GL11.GL_FLOAT, 0, 0l);

GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

//GL11.glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f); //i used this when i disable binding color buffer and color pointer

GL11.glDrawArrays(GL11.GL_QUADS, 0, numOfVertices);

GL11.glDisableClientState(GL11.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
GL11.glDisableClientState(GL11.GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
```

I have searched for a solution for a couple days now and haven't found one. my graphics card driver is up to date(i also installed a new graphics card a month ago if that makes any difference), i installed the latest version of java also.

Comment: You are going to laugh at yourself when you find out what you did wrong :) You called `glVertexPointer (...)` twice, the second call should be replaced with `glColorPointer (...)`. The crash occurs because you enabled the color array, but never actually setup a color pointer.

Comment: omfg. i even said in the question that i had used glcolorpointer. I do feel quite stupid now. i followed a tutorial exactly and couldn't figure it out. works like a charm now Thanks!